# Showing a View from another View in MVP

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, winforms, mvp

This question is regarding MVP triads. Lets say I have two triads and first one has `View1`, `Mode1` and `Presenter1`. Second triad has `View2`, `Model2` and `Presenter2`. Now what I trying to do is, I just want to display the `View2` when I click a `button` in `View1`.

You'd show the `View1` calling it's presenter's show method.

```
View1Presenter presenter1 = new View1Presenter (view1, Model1);
presenter1.show();
```

Now When I click `btnShowView2` button on the `View1`, it should display the `View2`.

So how to call `presenter2.show()` from `View1`?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about implementation and has already been posted at StackOverflow.

Comment: @maple_shaft: this question is IMHO clearly on-topic, since it is question about responsibilities in the code when follwing the MVP paradigm. It is not even language specific, C#/Winforms is here just an example, in Java, C++ or many other OO languages the question & answer would almost look like the same. Of course, it is a crosspost (and should be closed on SO!)

Comment: @DocBrown Thanks for bringing that to my attention.  I didn't read the question carefully enough.  I reopened.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Displaying a second view on `btnShowView2.Clicked` is some kind of business logic, so the right place for implementing this is in the event handler of `presenter1` which deals with that event (I assume that presenter1 is registered to all relevant button-click events of `View1`). Lets call it `HandleBtnView2Click`, so the initial code inside that handler might look like this:

```
  void HandleBtnView2Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e))
  {
       IView2 view2 = new View2();
       Model2 model2 = model1.GetRefToModel2(); // or whatever is needed to get model2
       View2Presenter presenter2 =new View2Presenter(view2,model2);
       presenter2.show();
  }
```

But actually, this is not a good solution, since it would imply the presenter2 layer must be linked against the UI library (in your case WinForms), which in worst case prevents automatic testing.

The better solution is to delegate the creation of `View2` to a third instance, which can be easily mocked out. In general, its possible to use an abstract factory for this. In the specific case, it is also possible to use `View1` for the creation of `View2`. Add a method to your `IView1` interface:

```
 interface IView1
 {
    // ...
      IView2 CreateView2();
 }
```

and use it in the code above:

```
  void HandleBtnView2Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e))
  {
       IView2 view2 = view1.CreateView2(); // view1 is of type IView1 and a member of presenter1
       Model2 model2 = model1.GetRefToModel2(); // or whatever is needed to get model2
       View2Presenter presenter2 =new View2Presenter(view2,model2);
       presenter2.show();
  }
```

Now when you want to automatically test your `presenter1`, provide it with a mock implementation of view1 which implements the `CreateView2` method in a manner returning a mock of view2. In the `View1` class, you implement `CreateView2()` to return the `new View2()`, so the responsibility for creating views stays at the the view layer.

You can go a step further if you want and make `presenter1` testable in isolation from `presenter2`. If you think that is necessary, create an interface `IPresenter2` and put the whole creation code above into an abstract "presenter factory":

```
   void HandleBtnView2Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e))
   {
        IPresenter presenter2 = presenterFactory.CreatePresenter2(model1);
        presenter2.show();
   }
```

The `presenterFactory` has to be injected into your presenter1 at construction time and can be replaced by a mock in your test suite. If that's necessary, you have to decide for yourself. It will add an additional layer of complexity to your code for the benefit of better testability.

Comment: very clear answer